What hook to use for bulk action on WooCommerce orders with HPOS
In Woocommerce 8.0.1 by adding the bottom code to functions.php of my theme I can add my bulk actions to Woocommerce order page:
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'register_custom_bulk_action' );
function register_custom_bulk_action( $bulk_actions ) {
    $bulk_actions['action_1'] = __( 'action 1', 'woocommerce' );
    $bulk_actions['action_2'] = __( 'action 2', 'woocommerce' );
    return $bulk_actions;
}

But the same code on a fresh install of Woocommerce 9.3.3 doesn't add my actions.
I tested on a fresh install of 8.0.1 and then updated it to version 9.3.3 and it worked after update.
Am I doing something wrong or this is an internal bug of Woocommerce?

Apparently the action name changed to bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders
